# media queries working in local development and in chrome but not in firefox or on all mobile devices?

Tags: css, google-chrome, firefox, responsive-design, cpanel

I updated the stylesheets on my new site(3days old) I have media queries it's showing on firefox dev tools but not rendering effect.

I already have 
I tested it in my local dev(working) also it is working in chrome
I also deleted all files in my public_html and uploaded a the updated stylesheets

I'm thinking could it be a caching issue with my host(bluehost) since it is a new site.
p.s. I could not find the clear cache on my bluehost dashboard

Comment: Please share the code that does'nt work to maybe find the error

Comment: thanks for repsponding @johannchopin `@media screen and (max-width: 768px)
 .navigation
  ul
   display: none
  img
   width: 120px
   height: 120px
   margin: 5px 15px
   padding: 5px 5px

 .hero
  margin: 50px
  text-align: right
  float: right
  border: none
  border-right: solid 5px $plum`

this is one of the media queries.. but I loooked in to the live sites code and I think there are some files that are not copied

Comment: Be sure that you see your file with this code inside online with your devTools